# Mongoose populate array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I can't get mongoose to populate an array of objects.

The schema is as follows:

```
var topOrganisationsForCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: String,
  topOrganisations: [{
    organisation: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'organisation'
    },
    model: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('topOrganisationsForCategory', topOrganisationsForCategorySchema);
```

I would like all of the objects in this collection populated with an array of organisations.

Here is what i have tried

```
TopOrganisationsForCategory
  .find()
  .exec(function(err, organisation) {
    var options = {
      path: 'topOrganisations.organisation',
      model: 'organisation'
    };

    if (err) return res.json(500);
    Organisation.populate(organisation, options, function(err, org) {
      res.json(org);
    });
  });

var organisationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  aliases: [String],
  categories: [String],
  id: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  idType: String
});

organisationSchema.index({
  name: 'text'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('organisation', organisationSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close but a couple notes:

- The following code assumes you also have a schema/model declaration for `Oranisation`.
- I am not sure if the `model` property is meant as an option (which would be invalid) or actually is a property of `topOrganisations`.

So, I left `model` in as it shouldn't cause any issues but be aware that if you were using it as an option it is **not** doing what you might think it is.

```
// Assuming this schema exists
var organisationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});

var topOrganisationsForCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  category: String,
  topOrganisations: [{
    organisation: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Organisation' // Model name convention is to begin with a capital letter
    }
    // Is `model` supposed to be for the ref above? If so, that is declared in the
    //  Organisation model
    model: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
  }]
});

// Assuming these model definitions exist
var Organisation = mongoose.model('Organisation', organisationSchema);
var TopOrganisationsForCategory = mongoose.model('TopOrganisationsForCategory', TopOrganisationsForCategorySchema);

// Assuming there are documents in the organisations collection

TopOrganisationsForCategory
  .find()
  // Because the `ref` is specified in the schema, Mongoose knows which
  //  collection to use to perform the population
  .populate('topOrganisations.organisation')
  .exec(function(err, orgs) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(500);
    }

    res.json(orgs);
  });
```

Comment: I do have a schema for organisation called "organisation" but it still does not work. It just returns the collection without the objects populated and only the id

Comment: @TJF Can you post your model/schema code for it? This should work unless there is an issue with naming consistency.

Comment: @TJF Ah. It is typical by convention to begin model names with a capital letter. In my example I am but in your code you are not. Can you check that all string values for a model name match both in definitions and in the ref option?

Comment: @TFJ I'm at a loss for why this isn't working. If you've verified there are matching documents in the organisations collection this should work.